# Solve an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

I need to find the sum of this series:
$1, 2 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}} \right ), 3 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}} \right ) ^ 2, 4 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}} \right ) ^ 3, 5 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}} \right ) ^ 4, ... $

I easily found the formula:
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}} \right ) ^ n$

but now I don't know how to find the solution without using limits. I know I could solve the limit:
$\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{k} (n+1) \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}} \right ) ^ n$

I was wondering if there is a way to solve the sum without using limits.

Comment: But you're familiar with the geometric series, yes?

Comment: Yes, familiar enough I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If you can do $\sum x^n$, $\frac{d}{dx}\sum x^n=\sum nx^{n-1}$ evaluated at the proper $x$ will get you there.

Comment: Isn't $\displaystyle\sum nx^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$?

Comment: OK, thank you, I replaced $1 - \frac{1}{15}$ instead of $1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$, a stupid error!